# Strongly-typed view difference (MVC sources vs. assembly)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, strong-typing

I'm trying to create a strongly typed partial view

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Pt.Data.Services>>" %>
<table>
  <% foreach (Pt.Data.Services item in Model)
       { Html.RenderPartial("ServiceItem",item); } %>
</table>
```

in the Controller:

```
IEnumerable<Services> Model=null;
using (tl ctx = new tl(Config.ConnectionString))
{
    Model = ctx.Services.ToList();
}
return View("List",Model);
```

This workied well when running in a project with the binary assembly `System.Web.Mvc` referenced.

But if I remove binary assembly and add a project with MVC sources for debugging, it stops recognizing strongly typed views.

It's working like a `ViewPage` instead of `ViewPage<TModel>`

As result I'm getting the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Why would this work with the compiled MVC, but not with the sources? And how can I make the sources run correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you changed this line in ~/Views/Web.config:

```
<pages validateRequest="false"
       pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter,
                             System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                             PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
       pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,
                     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
       userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl,
                            System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                            PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

to this?:

```
<pages validateRequest="false"
       pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter,
                             System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                             PublicKeyToken=NULL"
       pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,
                     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=NULL"
       userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl,
                            System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                            PublicKeyToken=NULL">
```

Actually this Steve Sanderson's [post](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/) might be helpful

Comment: No, I didn't set PublicKeyToken to NULL.
Really, it can help.
I will try now.

Comment: This has not worked for me. I was not able to find the View anymore

Comment: In case you updated the MVC framework version (by changing web.config files and references manually), you also need to change these version strings to e.g. 3.0.0.0 (for MVC 3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a reason that might cause a referenced source project to behave differently than its own build output(assembly). **Still I can recommend:** 
1- Make sure the source you're using is the same the assembly was built off.
2- Make sure you added a reference to the source project. 
3- RC on your solution file, choose clean solution, then rebuild and try again.

Comment: no positive result.

I guess maybe the reason is in compilation of MVC.
Compiled sources in release mode has a size of 179 712 bytes
But binary assembly from MVC release has a size of 186 176 bytes

Looks like some of generic classes are not compiled or something like that.